but Ireland has ever been a shipwreck coast
This sentence found in Colleen McCullough’s The Thorn Birds (1977) has been throwing me off:

His nose was magnificent, a true Roman nose which must have puzzled
his Irish confreres, but Ireland has ever been a shipwreck coast.

The last clause sounds like an incomprehensible non-sequitur. And is “ever” even compatible with “but” in this context? Shouldn’t there be a negative of some sort? I found no idiomatic usage whatsoever associated with “shipwreck coast.” Please help!

I believe several interpretations are possible from a purely linguistic perspective here. I think the language is at best unusual; I'd expect '... but then' or ', because' rather than ', but' here. I think it would be better asked on Literature.SE, where critics (and associates of McCullough) who might know more context might be referenced.

@EdwinAshworth I wonder whether the asker is unaware of how prolifically productive singular attributive noun alternation is with of +  plural noun in English. Surely nobody would bat at eye if they read a poppy field instead of a field of poppies, or a puppy kennel instead of a kennel for puppies. After all, a shipwreck coast is nothing more than a coast of shipwrecks or a coast for shipwrecks. Although not without exceptions blocking some pairings, this alternation seems much too productive for any dictionary to ever cover all possible collocations.

@tchrist I mentioned what I considered the major source of confusion to be ... the (on the surface) non-sequitur OP points out.

The use of 'ever' here is similar to that in 'forever' / 'for ever'

even tighter ;-p --- Eire has e'er boat-breaker been

Welcome new user.  "ever" means "always". (Why is this incredibly simple question causing so much discussion?)

"I found no idiomatic usage whatsoever associated with “shipwreck coast.”"  It just means "a coast where a lot of shipwrecks happened".  (What else could it mean?????). For example, LA is a film city, France is a wine nation, stack exchange is an Otaku site, ESPN is a sports channel, Jesus is a religious figure, Ford is a car company, etc.

Edwin and TChrist -  could you be wildly, spectacularly, over-thinking this?  OP just didn't know that ever means always.

The sense is "His Irish friends and neighbours must have wondered where he got his Roman nose from - but there have always been a lot of shipwrecks off the coast of Ireland." The speaker guesses that one of the man's ancestors must have been an Italian sailor who survived a shipwreck.
As @Mike M says, has ever been has rather an old-fashioned, literary flavour.

"…but Ireland has ever been a shipwreck coast" is that grammatical?

@Mari-LouA "ever" here is a synonym for "always," so yes, it is.

@phoog  The use of the Present Perfect threw me off, I would have expected the Past Simple or the Present Participle form: “… but Ireland was ever the shipwreck coast" or  "… Ireland being ever the shipwreck coast.” and that would explain inheriting the roman nose (via the Ancient Romans) in the past, not today.

@Mari-LouA I wonder why using the Present Perfect in but Ireland has always seen no end of shipwrecks off its coast seems unremarkable to me but not to you. Does pulling the adverb out front of both auxiliary and participle change your take on it as in always has seen? That’s a marked use because it doesn’t follow the normal rule to place those between auxiliary and participle, moving focus to the auxiliary. Even more markèd is adverbial inversion (common in literature but not speech): Ever/Always has Ireland seen shipwrecks. How about did see vs saw?

@tchrist   Do you seriously think your sentence with "always" is remarkable, extraordinary or strange to me? Really? What gives you that impression? Might I not find "…but he has ever been late to the party” to be odd-sounding compared to "he's aways been late to the party".

@Mari-LouA I'm sorry. I was only asking about why you were thrown off by the Present Perfect and had been expecting a SImple Past or a bare Present Participle. That part had nothing to do with ever, at least that I can see. Have I misunderstood you?

I think a variant that sounds not very off-putting would be "but Ireland has forever been a shipwreck coast". To me, having "forever" instead of "ever" sounds better for some reason, but I can't rationally tell why.

@SyedM.Sannan I think "ever" sounds slightly better. “I was ever a fighter, so---one fight more, The best and the last!"

@SpehroPefhany Hey, it does sound better in that example though. I guess I was just being paranoid.

@tchrist my understanding is that the "ever" turns the apparently perfect tense into a continuous one that refers to "all time up until the present"; similarly with "had always been" which leads up to the time being spoken / written about.

We might add that, while perhaps not confusing to a native speaker, it does sound "literary" and not something we might use much in conversation.  And, indeed, the reference to shipwrecks is asking the listener/reader to put some work in to make the connection, at least today where i am;   maybe in another time or place it is a more common reference, perhaps a pejorative one against "outsiders". --- oh, other answer covered this

@Mari-LouA. "ever" means "always".  (Why is this super-simple question getting so much discussion??)

@Mari-LouA "was ever the ..." would be PAST tense.  It would be extremely strange to use that.  For example, "In the era 2000BC to 1000BC, Ireland was ever the blah coast".  It would be like saying "At that time, Eireland was always the blah coast."   That's bizarre.  Ireland "is" ("now") "always the blah coast".  Surely you have said to a friend "You're always the joker, Fattie" or "You're always the smartaas, Fattie" .. type of thing?

"he's aways been late to the party" is totally weird.  "He's always late to the party."  "he's aways been late to the party" would be a mistaken version of something (bizarre / exceedingly contrived) along the lines of "Back in the 70s he was constantly drunk and when we'd reminisce on that in the 90s we'd always say he's alway been late to the party ..."  (Or something bizarre like that.)

@SyedM.Sannan. - newsflash, the word "ever" MEANS "always".   :)  No matter how it sounds to you.  "Forever" is a totally different meaning.

@Fattie Hah, makes sense!

"A shipwreck coast" is a slightly odd (and rather literary) way of saying "a coast where a lot of shipwrecks happen."
"Ever" means "always" here (compare German "immer").  This is also literary to the point of seeming self-consciously so.  (It would be more at home in a work from the 18th or 19th century than one from 1977.)
The contrast justifying "but" is between the fact of shipwrecks and the friends' bewilderment at the Roman nose, the implication being that the friends should have thought of the shipwrecks and realized that the Roman nose wasn't so bewildering after all.

Yes; 'ever' is a negative-polarity item, and its rather jarring use with a positive declarative is literary.

@EdwinAshworth why is "ever" a negative-polarity item?  Where is the negative polarity in, e.g., "henceforward I am ever ruled by you"?

You don't think that's a literary / archaic usage? See John Lawler's seminal answer.

I don't really know what I'm talking about, but it strikes me that in this context, "ever" and "never" are antonyms.  "... but Ireland has never been a shipwreck coast" makes modern grammatical sense, even if reversing the meaning.

@Digital Trauma But 'never' and 'ever' have different distributions: 'Have you never been to Leeds by helicopter? / 'Have you ever been to Leeds by helicopter? BUT 'I have never been to Leeds by helicopter' / *'I have ever been to Leeds by helicopter.'

@EdwinAshworth I absolutely think it's literary/archaic, which accounts for the second paragraph of this answer.  I don't understand your comment about "ever" being a negative polarity item or about this use being jarring.  I suppose the degree to which it is jarring depends on one's degree of exposure to literary and archaic writing, but that doesn't help me to understand the point about negative polarity.

German here, how does comparing it to "immer" help?

If someone said "He ever makes the effort to see his old aunt when he is in the Northeast', instead of using 'always', they would be seen as not using idiomatic English. There is a violation of the negative polarity item constraint (in this case, not ungrammatical in stylised literature). See Esipova et al. // This is giving more detail than a mere 'confined to literature / archaic works'.

While positive ever is certainly no longer standard in colloquial English, I’m not sure it’s confined just to archaic/literary usage — my impression is that it has remained current longer in Irish English, which would help explain its use in The Thorn Birds (an Australian novel, but incorporating a lot of Irish English).  I haven’t found a strong source to back up my impression, but as circumstantial evidence, one of the OED’s most recent citations is from the 1977 Concise Ulster Dictionary: “It came from Athlone, so they just ever called it Athlone.”

The historical context for this is the Spanish Armada of 1588, which was soundly defeated by Drake and ended up hightailing it for home around the top of Scotland and down the West coast of Ireland. A good number of the bedraggled ships of the Armada foundered off the Irish coast, leaving many Spanish sailors to their own devices, which -- sailors being sailors -- resulted in a crop of mixed-race babies in 1589. Some of these babies had Roman noses, at least by Irish standards.
Oh, and "ever" can mean "always" in literary prose.

And the ships of the Armada were manned by sailors of multiple countries, including Italy.

Why the Spanish Armada specifically? It seems very odd that mention of a Roman nose  would be related to a Spanish fleet just because some of the sailors could perhaps have hailed from lands that used to be Roman. Indeed, the use of ever suggests a continuous, long period of time, so it is very unlikely to be a reference to any single occurrence.

@terdon: Because there was not, is not, and never will be an "Italian armada".

Um. True, as far as the past goes anyway, but why would there need to be an armada? All the passage is saying is that the Irish coast has been the site of many shipwrecks over many years so people from all over may have been washed ashore. No need for any armada to be involved.

@terdon, it was never routine for a trade ship to founder off the Irish coast! But the Spanish Armada was in full retreat, in bad condition, and was met with severe weather. (Having said that, there are dissenting voices regarding the Spanish Armada explanation.)

@A.I.Breveleri  There were one, but Tarranto happened. (The Fairey Swordfish sank more axis shipping in the Western theatre than any other aircraft).

"Ever" means "always." (As you can see in any dictionary.)

This answer was given two days ago, you're a bit late to the party.

To be late to the party is an idiom, there's nothing totally weird, as you affirmed, about "He's always been late to the party."
